# Search/replace in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

Use case: Remove a string from Azure Application Insights results

This is a simple question but with minimal examples online and as a new user, and with limited experience (but learning) in Regex, I am struggling.

How do I remove all instances of `| Articles` in the following table, which is an example of what I am exporting from Azure Application Insights?

[image]

This did not work:

```
| extend name=replace(@' | Articles', @'', name)
```

I have fiddled quite a bit unsuccessfully with an example in Microsoft's documentation (I know this interpretation is incorrect):

```
| extend str=strcat(' | Articles', tostring(name))
| extend replaced=replace(@' | Articles', @'', str)
```

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the reason your initial attempt doesn't work is that the first argument to `replace()` is a regular expression, and if you have the pipe (`|`) in is, you'll need to properly escape it, using a backslash (`\`).

for example:

```
datatable(s:string)
[
    "Article 1 | Articles",
    "Article 2",
    "Article 3 | Articles" 
]
| extend replaced=replace(@' \| Articles', @'', s)
```

ideally, you'll choose a solution that doesn't require using a regular expression, if possible.

for example:

```
datatable(s:string)
[
    "Article 1 | Articles",
    "Article 2",
    "Article 3 | Articles" 
]
| extend i = indexof(s, " | Articles")
| project s = case(i == -1, s, substring(s, 0, i))
```